# org.omg.CORBA.INTERNAL: CONNECTIONINTERCEPTOR_INVALID_CLASSNAME vmcid: 0x49421000 minor code: 5B completed: No

Tags: java

Recently I migrated the application from WAS 6.0 to WAS 7.0  and java 1.4 to java 5, when I am trying to launch the application from WAS 7 server I got the below error but it works fine with my RAD 7.5 environment.

```
org.omg.CORBA.INTERNAL: CONNECTIONINTERCEPTOR_INVALID_CLASSNAME  vmcid: 0x494210
00  minor code: 5B  completed: No
        at com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSTransport.init(WSTransport.java:208)
        at com.ibm.rmi.corba.PluginRegistry.initPlugin(PluginRegistry.java:224)
        at com.ibm.rmi.corba.PluginRegistry.initPlugins(PluginRegistry.java:210)
        at com.ibm.rmi.corba.PluginRegistry.initPlugin(PluginRegistry.java:193)
        at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ORB.initializePrereqPlugins(ORB.java:576)
        at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ORB.orbParameters(ORB.java:1299)
        at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ORB.set_parameters(ORB.java:1225)
        at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ORB.set_parameters(ORB.java:1681)
        at org.omg.CORBA.ORB.init(ORB.java:364)
        at com.ibm.ws.orb.GlobalORBFactory.init(GlobalORBFactory.java:82)
        at com.ibm.ejs.oa.EJSORBImpl.initializeORB(EJSORBImpl.java:174)
        at com.ibm.ejs.oa.EJSClientORBImpl.<init>(EJSClientORBImpl.java:97)
        at com.ibm.ejs.oa.EJSClientORBImpl.<init>(EJSClientORBImpl.java:73)
        at com.ibm.ejs.oa.EJSORB.init(EJSORB.java:386)
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.Helpers.getOrb(Helpers.java:285)
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getInitialContextInternal(Ws
nInitCtxFactory.java:373)
```

I am new to WAS 7 server, please help me out. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is resolved now.. Previously i used IBM WAS 7 JRE to launch the application . now i changed to IMB JDK .. application works fine..

Thanks to all.. :)